# How to ignore touch event, and let the ImageView below handle it as a zoom gesture(if applicable)?

Tags: android

I have a custom ImageView control that supports zooming (TouchImageView). On top of this view there is a seekbar. I want the seekbar to work only when the user clicks or drags the thumb of the seekbar. If the user clicks on the seekbar, but not the thumb, then the ImageView underneath should receive the touch event or gesture.

Here is my code. I managed to send the touch event to the ImageView with dispatchTouchEvent, but the ImageView only receives a touch event. I need it to receive a zoom gesture (Of course only when the user makes a zoom gesture. If the user only makes a touch event, then the ImageView should receive only a touch event).

```
    seekbarHorizontal.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

            float x = arg1.getX();
            float thumbOffset = seekbarHorizontal.getThumbOffset();

            if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                if(x < seekbarHorizontal.getProgress() - thumbOffset || x > seekbarHorizontal.getProgress() + thumbOffset)
                {
                    sendSeekbarHorizontalTouchEventTo = "image";
                    imgRight.dispatchTouchEvent(arg1);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    sendSeekbarHorizontalTouchEventTo = "seekbar";
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(sendSeekbarHorizontalTouchEventTo.equals("image"))
                {
                    imgRight.dispatchTouchEvent(arg1);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: The seekbar contains a slider I assume? Shouldn't a FrameLayout draw it on top of your other elements and handle this out of the box? I think you want to use a [more specific listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.html) instead though

Comment: @G_V: Yes, the seekbar and the image are in a FrameLayout. But how do I handle it out of the box? How does the gesture event reach the ImageView without the seekbar catching the event (because the seekbar is at the top)?

Comment: I assume you have an activity that contains them both. Implement the listener on the activity, pass it to the seekbar. The activity has access to the ImageView and should be able to manipulate it. Essentially you manually pass the event down to the method you want to respond.